# c++ multiple operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to overload some operators multiple times and i am not sure how to do it i have a class

for example

```
int main(){
    addClass c1;
    addClass c2;
    addClass c1 = (c2 + 10 * c2 + 2 * c3)*c3; 
}
```

my problem is that i dont know how to make this many opreator ovrloading, I mean what do i need to return in ordear for it to continue to the next opreator? 
I tried that

```
    class addClass 
    //declration
        friend addClass & operator*(const double, const addClass &);

    addClass & operator*(double x, const addClass & a1)
    {
        int i;
        addClass add(a1.rank);
    add.res=x*a1.res
        }
        return res;
    }
```

but for the next oprators i run into some problems so i wanted to know what to do

Thank you!

Comment: What problems did you run into? Give specific error messages that you got.

Comment: Are you sure this is your actual code? It is syntactically incorrect. Additionally, there are no members called `rank` and `res`. Also, you return `res`, which is not a variable declared in your code. It would help if you provide us with the actual code and the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of evaluation is the same as usual even for overloaded operators, so with this example where I've added printing in the operators ...

```
#include <iostream>

class addClass {
public:
    addClass() : addClass(0) {}

    // converting constructor
    addClass(int x) : value(x) {}

    addClass& operator+=(const addClass& rhs) {
        value += rhs.value;
        return *this;
    }
    addClass& operator-=(const addClass& rhs) {
        value -= rhs.value;
        return *this;
    }    
    addClass& operator*=(const addClass& rhs) {
        value *= rhs.value;
        return *this;
    }
    addClass& operator/=(const addClass& rhs) {
        value /= rhs.value;
        return *this;
    }

    int getValue() const { return value; }
private:
    int value;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const addClass& ac) {
    return os << ac.getValue();
}

addClass operator+(addClass lhs, const addClass& rhs) {
    std::cout << lhs << '+' << rhs << '=';
    lhs += rhs;
    std::cout << lhs << '\n';
    return lhs;
}
addClass operator-(addClass lhs, const addClass& rhs) {
    std::cout << lhs << '-' << rhs << '=';
    lhs -= rhs;
    std::cout << lhs << '\n';
    return lhs;
}
addClass operator*(addClass lhs, const addClass& rhs) {
    std::cout << lhs << '*' << rhs << '=';
    lhs *= rhs;
    std::cout << lhs << '\n';
    return lhs;
}
addClass operator/(addClass lhs, const addClass& rhs) {
    std::cout << lhs << '/' << rhs << '=';
    lhs /= rhs;
    std::cout << lhs << '\n';
    return lhs;
}

int main(){
    addClass c1;
    addClass c2 = 100;
    addClass c3 = 2;
    c1 = (c2 + 10 * c2 / 2 * c3)*c3;
}
```

... you would get this output:

```
10*100=1000
1000/2=500
500*2=1000
100+1000=1100
1100*2=2200
```